# Count list with parameters?

Tags: c#

I have two class lists teams, and matches

In my teams class I have a int id and string name and on the matches class I have int team1Id and 
team2Id, I want to know if there's a way to count on matches list how many matches a team participate..

Like

```
if(teamlist.id == matcheslist.team1 || teamlist.id == matcheslist.team2) count++;
```

Sorry if I didn't explain very well, english isn't my first language.

EDIT1:

Here the lists, 
        public List teams= new List();
        public List matches = new List();
Team and Match are my classes, with basic information, id and name for Team and id, team1 and team2 for Match, I tried to use find but it only return one result

Comment: you can use linq, but your question is too unclear to answer. can you post some code and example?  (like how your lists look for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sort of setup:

```
class Team {
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}

class Match {
    public Team[] Teams { get; set; }
}

var matches = new List<Match>() { 
    new Match() {
        Teams = new Team[] {
            new Team() { TeamId = 1 },
            new Team() { TeamId = 2 } 
        }
    },
    new Match() {
        Teams = new Team[] {
            new Team() { TeamId = 1 },
            new Team() { TeamId = 15 } 
        }
    }
};
```

You can count them like so:

```
var teamOneGameCount = matches.Count(match => match.Teams.Any(team => team.TeamId == 1));
var teamTwoGameCount = matches.Count(match => match.Teams.Any(team => team.TeamId == 2));
var teamFifteenGameCount = matches.Count(match => match.Teams.Any(team => team.TeamId == 15));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is linq example:

```
List<Teamlist> item1 = new List<Teamlist>();
List<Matcheslist> item2 = new List<Matcheslist>();
var count = item1.Count(c => item2.Any(c2 => c2.Id2 == c.Id1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
List<teamlist> list = new List<teamlist>();
int count = 0;
list.Add(team1);
list.Add(team2);
...
foreach(teamlist tl in list)
{
    if(teamlist.id == matcheslist.team1 || teamlist.id == matcheslist.team2) count++;
}
```

Is that "List" keyword you need ?
Or you need a LINQ query operation like:

```
using System.Linq;
...
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(new []{1,2,3,4,5,6});
int count = list.Count(n => n > 2); // 4
```